# Generic type safety warning

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, type-safety

I'm getting the type safety warning everywhere in the program and I'm pretty sure I did something wrong the with the usage of generics. The warning is displayed in code mostly that has Node involved. Please point out the parts where my syntax is possibly not the most ideal and recommend changes to my code. Appreciate any help!

Removing the  in Node class works!

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private class Node<T>{

    private T data;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    // left and right child do not have to nessary exist
    public Node ( T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null; 
    }}

    private Node<T>root;
    private int count = 0;

    public void add( T data) {
        if ( isEmpty()) {
            root = new Node(data);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            insert(data, root);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {  
        return root == null;
    }

    public T getRoot()  {
        if ( root.data == null) {
            System.out.println("Root is empty");
            return null;
        }
        else {
        return  root.data;
    }}

    /*
     * Checking if the data is larger or lesser than the parent's data
     * If the data is smaller than the parent's data, node.left is created 
     * If the data is bigger than the parent's data, node.right is created
     */
    private void insert( T data, Node<T>node) {

        /*
         * If 1st obj is less than the 2nd obj return a neg
         * if 1st obj is more than the 2nd obj return a pos
         * if equal return 0
         */
        int compare = data.compareTo(node.data);
        if ( compare < 1 ){
            if (node.left == null ) {
                node.left = new Node(data);

            }

        // make node.left if it is filled   
            else {
                insert(data, node.left);
            }
        }

        else {
            if ( node.right == null) {
                node.right = new Node(data);
            }
            else {
                insert( data, node.right);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Both `left` and `right` are raw types (i.e. `Node` instead of `Node<T>`). **However**, it looks like the _class_ `Node` should not have a type parameter in the first place; since it's an inner (i.e. non-static, nested) class it "inherits" the `T` from the enclosing `BinaryTree` class. Currently the `T` of `Node` is _hiding_ the `T` of `BinaryTree`.

Comment: @Slaw: Yup. Um.. just turn that into an answer so that can be upvoted and receive the checkmark (I was halfway through writing the same thing as an answer, but then your comment popped up and there is nothing more to add, except perhaps: Alternatively, make the Node class static and keep the <T>).

Comment: @rzwitserloot At the time I didn't feel my comment warranted a full answer (I later wrote one, but then deleted it). As you were already writing an answer the credit can go to you if you want to still finish writing it (it's not like you're copying me or anything, you separately had the same idea at the same time). Though I wouldn't recommend making `Node` a static class; conceptually it makes more sense for it to share the `T` with `BinaryTree`.